# Setting model data after validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to set data in a FormModel after validation. Example of a use case here is if I want to assign a unique number to a form data set if and only if it passes validation. There's some other information I'm trying to tack on too that isn't available prior to validation. I've tried setting in both the view class and in the clean() method of the ModelForm but can't seem to get it right. Each time I get an exception saying that "tag_id" cannot be null. Obviously I'm not setting it in a way that let's form.save() access the data.

Note that in the example below I'm trying to set tag_id in two places to illustrate what I've tried; obviously only one place would be needed if it worked.

What is the proper way to do this?

Model and FormModel:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    tag_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField()
    size = models.BigIntegerField()
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'videos'


class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['name', 'video_file']

    def clean(self):
        self.data['tag_id'] = 10
        return self.cleaned_data
```

The view class:

```
class Upload(FormView):
    template_name = "account/templates/upload.html"
    form_class = VideoForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.cleaned_data['tag_id'] = 10
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Exception on form.save():

```
IntegrityError at /account/upload/
(1048, "Column 'tag_id' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the attribute of the model instance:

```
form.instance.tag_id = 10
form.save()
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew it had to be something simple. I think both of these answers are probably valid but I'm going with this one. Thanks.